# Python, Using Remote Managers and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use the remote manager functions in the `multiprocessing` module to distribute work among many machines.  I know there are 3rd party modules, but I want to stick with core as much as possible.  I know for desktop (single machine), you can use the `multiprocessing.Pool` class to limit the number of CPUs, but have a couple of questions with remote managers.

I have the following code for the remote manager:

```
   from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
   import Queue
   queue = Queue.Queue()
   class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
   QueueManager.register('get_queue', callable=lambda:queue)
   m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')
   s = m.get_server()
   s.serve_forever()
```

This works great, and I can even submit a job into the Queue using the following code:

```
QueueManager.register('get_queue')
m = QueueManager(address=('machinename', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')
m.connect()
queue = m.get_queue()
queue.put('hello')
```

You can also the `queue.get()` to get a single entry in the queue.

1. How do you get the items in the queue?  When I tried to iterate through the queue, I enter an infinite loop.
2. On the workers, can you limit each machine to 1 job per machine?
3. Since this method seems to be a pull method, where the workers need to examine if a job exists, can there be a push method where the multiprocessing server can be triggered?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a queue is the same as doing:

```
while True:
    elem = queue.get()  #queue empty -> it blocks!!!
```

An elegant way to "iterate" over a queue *and block your worker process when there are no more jobs to execute* is to use `None`(or something else) as a sentinel and use `iter(callable, sentinel)`:

```
for job in iter(queue.get, None):
    # execute the calculation
    output_queue.put(result)

#shutdown the worker process
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
while True:
    job = queue.get()
    if job is None:
        break
    #execute the calculation
    output_queue.put(result)
#shutdown the worker process
```

Note that you have to insert in the queu a sentinel for each worker subprocess, otherwise there will be subprocesses waiting for it.

Regarding your second question, I don't understand what you are asking. The `BaseManager` provides *one* server that executes the calls from the clients, so, obviously, all requests are satisfied by the same machine. 
Or do you mean allow each client to do only a request? I don't see any option for this, even though it could be implemented "by hand".

I don't understand your question. *What* is like a pull method? Can you rephrase your question with a bit more details on what you mean by "a push method where the multiprocessing server can be triggered"?

Comment: Thank you for the iteration method.

Comment: So I guess my question is this, say you have a single remote manager, that always run, and you have multiple workers.  What is the best method to ensure only one worker machine does one job? Is there a way to manually assigned a job to a worker machine? When a worker machine pulls a job using the get(), do that job get removed from the queue?

Comment: @josh1234 Once a job is obtained via `get` the other processes wont receive it anymore. That's exactly the purpose of the queue: it automatically handles the synchronisation between processes to avoid that the same job is performed by more than a worker.